# alias for 2 app and NLB

Tags: alias, nlb

i used the "-" in app name and http but please remove it, it is just because i cannot add more than 2 links. i just put like a code because i had issues of formatting

```
    Hi  
    i have 3 server  
    1) DC d-o-m-a-i-n controller  
    2) S-R-V-1  
    3) S-R-V-2  

    DC has d-o-m-a-i-n xxx.yyy and IP 10.21.221.145  
    S-R-V-1 has IP 10.21.221.146  
    S-R-V-2 has IP 10.21.221.147  

    in S-R-V-1 i have 2 web application , a-p-p-1 , a-p-p-2  
    a-p-p-1 runs in port 9643 using h-t-t-ps  
    a-p-p-2 runs in port 443 using h-t-t-p-s  

    so i have u-r-l like  
    h-t-t-p-s://s-r-v-1.xxx.yyy:9643/a-p-p-1  
    h-t-t-p-s://s-r-v-1.xxx.yyy/a-p-p-2  

    same for s-r-v-2 where i have same web application running on same port  

    h-t-t-p-s://s-r-v-2.xxx.yyy:9643/a-p-p-1  
    h-t-t-p-s://s-r-v-2.xxx.yyy/a-p-p-2  

    i have created also wildcard certificate and FQDN certificate  
    *.xxx.yyy  
    s-r-v-1.xxx.yyy  
    s-r-v-2.xxx.yyy  

    now i want to create an alias for app1 so that i can use  
    h-t-t-p-s://w-e-b-1:9643/a-p-p-1  
    and an alias for a-p-p-2 so that i can use  
    h-t-t-p-s://w-e-b-2/a-p-p-2  

    so now i want to create a cluster NLB based on microsoft  
    as far as i know i need to install the feature of NLB in both servers srv1 and srv2  
    and create a cluster with IP 10.21.221.10 for example and add the 2 servers  
    let's call the cluster SRVCLU  
    so i can use h-t-t-p-s://SRVCLU:9643/app1 and h-t-t-p-s://SRVCLU/app2  
    but i can i do to use the 2 aliases above?
```

Comment: Could you please clarify why you need these aliases? When you are using NLB, you will have everything published under a single hostname, i.e., srvclu.xxx.yyy, so you aliases seems to be useless.

Comment: So, you would like to access these web applications using a different hostname than srvclu. Would it be enought to create CNAME in DNS so that both web1 and web2 are aliases of SRVCLU? This way you will access both apps using both aliases.

Comment: Hello eppesuig , do you mind to explain how to do that?, just create a CNAME entry in DNS? how could be setted?

Comment: Yes, if you create two CNAMEs "web1" and "web2" for srvclu, then your browser will ask the dns for webX, get the ip address, then connect to the NLB and IIS. the problem is that you will have ALL URLs working: web1:9643/app1 and web1/app2 and web2:9643/app1 and web2/app2. You might probably work on IIS in order to block those unwanted URLs.